# Using responsebody in Postman re-usable test

Tags: javascript, postman

I've been using [these](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-team-collections/request/1372588-f5a382fb-c5cb-4fbd-af23-4a5b0ce89cb1) examples to reuse requests, pre-requests scripts and test. They work great, but I've hit a snag.

I have two collections, a library and an implementation. In the library, I have a request called "MyRequest".

I reference that request like this :

```
eval(pm.variables.get("executeReferencedRequest"));
executeReferencedRequest({
collectionUUID: postman.getEnvironmentVariable("libraryCollectionUuid"),
requestName: "MyReqest"
}, () => {

eval(pm.variables.get("referencedPreRequestScript"));
pm.request.update(pm.variables.get("referencedRequest"));
eval(pm.variables.get("referencedTestScript"));

eval(pm.variables.get("referencedPreRequestScript"));

});
```

The request fires off, and does what it should. In my Library.MyRequest, I have this as a Test :

```
if (responseBody)
{
    console.log(responsebody);
}
```

In my implementation, I have this:

```
var test = pm.variables.get("referencedTestScript");
if (test) {
    eval(test);
}
```

When I fire off the Library's request itself, it works, and I get a response out. When I fire this from the implementation, however. I get this error:

> ReferenceError: responseBody is not defined

It appears that the responsebody is not available in the implementation's scope. Is there any way I can still access it?

Answer (score 0):

Using this, I am able to get the response in the calling/implementation:

```
pm.response.text()
```